# Access data from an array of dates

Tags: reactjs

My application can get data from user. For this i have different inputs. One of my inputs is date Picker.

```js
 <Form.Item name="Picker" label="date">
        <RangePicker
          showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
          format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
          onChange={onChange2}
          onOk={onOk}
        />
 </Form.Item>
```

The issue appear when i try to access data after clicking on `submit` button. In console i have all data from each input, but from RangePicker, the data is not structured, and i get:

```js
Picker: Array[2]
0: Moment
1: Moment
```

The problem is that i can access this array, and display on  fron end. How to do this?

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-kbwgk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import moment from 'moment'

const onFinish = values => {
    const startDate = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    const endDate = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    console.log(startDate, endDate)
};
```

Comment: i tried: `const onOk = values => {
    const startDate = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    const endDate = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    console.log(startDate, endDate)
}`  but i got  `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: do you want to get date in `onFinish` or `onOk` func?

Comment: if in `onOk` it must be `value[0]`

Comment: i understand, probably onFinish is what i want, but i cen get all data, meaning, i tried, but i can't get all data: from RangePicker and from the rest of inputs, could you show me please, in my code

Comment: i tried this: `const onFinish = values => {
    const startDate = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    const endDate = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    const newV = {
      ...values,
      start: startDate,
      end: endDate
    }
    console.log( newV)
};`  but i got `TypeError: (0 , _moment.moment) is not a function` What could be the issue?

Comment: do you import `moment`?

Comment: yes, i imported it   https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-kbwgk

Comment: can you check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-2utq1) i see it good

Comment: you import wrong, it should be `import moment from 'moment'` as my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting it as an array of moment objects,try using moment js for formatting the moment js according to your needs

https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-sy4uq

```
function onOk(value) {
    const start = moment(value[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    const end = moment(value[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(start, end);
}

const onFinish = values => {
    const start = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    const end = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(start, end)
};
```

Comment: i tried, but i can't get all data: from RangePicker and from the rest of inputs, could you show me please, in my code

Comment: i tried this: const onFinish = values => { const startDate = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); const endDate = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); const newV = { ...values, start: startDate, end: endDate } console.log( newV) }; but i got TypeError: (0 , _moment.moment) is not a function What could be the issue?

Comment: the way you are importing moment was wrong. Fixed it for you.https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-sy4uq

Answer (score 1):

I got it,
on your rangepicker use
onFinish instead of onOk

```
<RangePicker
      showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
      format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
      onChange={onChange2}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    />
```

working as specified

you press Ok twice , so the first onOk still doesnt include the second part of the range
sorry for not giving professional answer

Comment: <RangePicker
          showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
          format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
          onChange={onChange2}
          onFinish={onFinish}
        />

Comment: i tried this: const onFinish = values => { const startDate = moment(values.Picker[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); const endDate = moment(values.Picker[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); const newV = { ...values, start: startDate, end: endDate } console.log( newV) }; but i got TypeError: (0 , _moment.moment) is not a function What could be the issue?